# Eclipse Generic Warning : Type safety: Unchecked cast from T to E

Tags: generics, unchecked-cast

How I can avoid generic warnings in the following code? 
Eclipse Generic Warning : Type safety: Unchecked cast from T to E

Is there a way to improve this code. Just putting and removing values from Stack.

```
public static <T, K, E> void genericStack(T a, K b) {
    Stack<E> st = new Stack<E>();
    st.push((E) a);
    st.push((E) b);
    b = (K) st.pop();
    a = (T) st.pop();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `T` and `K` parameters?

Comment: T and K can be anything like Integer, String, which can be pushed into the stack.  for example:

Comment: If `T` and `K` can be anything then you don't need to use generics and you can just use `Object`. There's no way to make this safe if there's no relationship between the types you're using.